# Azure pipelines is giving timeout for helm upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

At some point, Azure DevOps pipelines started to return "timeout" for helm tasks, after expending 3+ mins executing the task.

UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition (see the image).

[image: Image of the task outputs showing timeout]

It was somehow misleading because the error was happening at the same time they had an incident with some of the services in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error was the lack of capacity in the target AKS cluster. Apparently, the task timed out while waiting for some provisioning to happen or something like that.